# How to bypass Program Compatibility Assistant in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

I try to install DeamonTools Lite v4.47, this version has no ads, so installing the newer version is no option. I used it with no problems on Windows 7. However, I can't install it on Windows 11!
I tried to disable Program Compatibility Assistant in gpedit, but it doesn't work, still got a popup saying this app won't work. Is there any solution to fix this?

[image]

I managed to run it without installing it, I just extracted files from the installer, but still, I can't install sptd driver due to PCA dialog.

I installed sptd driver by downloading it newer version. But I still need a solution to bypass PCA for other installers. It can't be that Windows will decide what can be run on MY computer.

Unfortunately, installed sptd version is not compatible with this Daemon Tools. Still need a solution for PCA bypass.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, what exactly makes you think it will be compatible? It's an old tool that is less useful nowadays, how do you know it was coded to work on Windows 11?

Comment: It actually runs, I extracted files from installed and it works but I can't still install spdt driver due to PCA dialog.

Comment: I mean... GUI can run but that doesn't mean that the program will work fine. Even if you force the driver installation somehow.

Comment: You should translate the error message for those of us who can't read it ourselves. Questions are expected to be in English here on Super User and that includes error messages or at least to be provided a translated error message. I suspect the error message is generated by DeamonTools not Windows but I won't know that until the full English translation is provided.

Answer (score 1):

The version you have will not run in Windows 11.

No option, or not:  You will need to get Version 10 (thereabouts) to run in Windows 11.

Version 4 is just too old.

Comment: I managed to run it without installing, I just extracted files from installer, but still I can't install sptd driver due to PCA dialog.

Comment: I installed sptd driver by downloading it newer version. Unfortunately it's not compatible with this version of Daemon Tools. Also I still need solution to bypass PCA for other installers. It can't be that Windows will decide what can be run on MY computer.

Comment: Bypassing PCA for other installers is a different question

Comment: *It can't be that Windows will decide what can be run on MY computer* You have the option not to use Windows at all. If you do then, like any other OS, it really "decides" what can and what can't run. Also I suggest you read and understand the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[DAEMON Tools Ultra on Windows 10 version 1903](https://ultra.daemon-help.com/installation/windows_1903/)
says :

> With Windows 10 version 1903, Microsoft has implemented several crucial kernel changes that have significant influence on many apps and driver-based software. After deep investigation of the upcoming features, we came to the conclusion that it is impossible to make STPD driver compatible with the new operating system version and so will stop its support starting from 1903.

But it offers a remedy :

> In case you still want to use SCSI and IDE drives, there is a way to make them work on the new OS. Download and launch [this file](http://files.disc-soft.com/filer/shared/1558622682/287/) that changes two registry entries and reboot your PC. Once you start DAEMON Tools Ultra, you will see SCSI and IDE related features. Please note that this process disables default Windows protection introduced in the May update that keeps the system safe from vulnerabilities.

Note that this file seems to disable security protections that were
introduced to protect against the Spectre/Meltdown vulnerabilities.

I reproduce the file `turnonsptd.reg` here :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"FeatureSettingsOverride"=dword:00020000
"FeatureSettingsOverrideMask"=dword:00020000
```

It's possible that with these registry changes, you might be able
to install the sptd driver from v4.47.

Before doing any registry changes, I suggest creating at least a
System Restore point, to be able to undo the changes.
I also suggest exporting the registry key to a backup file
using `regedit`.

Comment: If it were as simply as implement a registry fix, surely DeamonTools, would have determined that as a possible way forward.  I agree with you on face value, versions that only supported the STPD driver, are incompatible with newer versions of Windows.